# Error inflating class Button

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-xml

Разметка кнопки:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button"

        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:text="@string/btn_register"
        android:textColor="#F77062"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

drawable/button.xml

```
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="340dp"
android:height="56dp"
android:viewportWidth="340"
android:viewportHeight="56"
>

<group>

    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M 2 0L 338 0C 339.105 0 340 0.895431 340 2L 340 54C 340 55.1046 339.105 56 338 56L 2 56C 0.895431 56 0 55.1046 0 54L 0 2C 0 0.895431 0.895431 0 2 0Z"
        />

    <group
        android:translateX="0"
        android:translateY="1"
        android:pivotX="170"
        android:pivotY="28"
        android:scaleX="2.828"
        android:scaleY="2.828"
        android:rotation="-45"
        >

        <path
            android:pathData="M 0 0L 0 56L 340 56L 340 0"
            >

            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">

                <gradient
                    android:type="linear"

                    >

                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFF"
                        android:offset="0"
                        />

                    <item
                        android:color="#edd1d1"
                        android:offset="1"
                        />

                </gradient>

            </aapt:attr>

        </path>

    </group>

</group>
```

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ru.vpiska"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 26
    versionName "3.2.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
```

На адройде версии 7+ все работает, если брать ниже, то уже появляется ошибка :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{ru.vpiska/ru.vpiska.auth.LoginActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating 
class Button
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File 
res/drawable/button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08005e
```

Comment: gradle какая версия у вас?

Comment: Версия Gradle - 3.0.1

Comment: LoginActivity от какого класса унаследован?

Comment: От AppCompatActivity

Comment: appcompat-v7 какая версия?

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0